# Python cfscrape error: Missing Node.js runtime

Tags: python, node.js, web-scraping, dependencies, cloudflare

I am trying to use cfscrape in Python 3.6 to bypass cloudflare:

```
import cfscrape
scraper = cfscrape.create_scraper()  # returns a CloudflareScraper instance
url = "https://..."
print(scraper.get(url).content)
```

But it gives me the following error:

> OSError: Missing Node.js runtime. Node is required. Please read the
>   cfscrape README's Dependencies section:
>   https://github.com/Anorov/cloudflare-scrape#dependencies.

The thing is I have installed all dependencies and I can run node e.g. via terminal:

`node -v` gives me --> `v8.9.1`

So what am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After restarting my computer, everything worked